# How should I write "push onto/on (the) stack"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, sentence-construction

I would like to know which of the following expressions are not correct and why:

1. push onto the stack
2. push onto stack
3. push on the stack
4. push on stack

Is there a good guide or rule on how to use ***onto***?

Answer (score 5):

In programming contexts, the idiomatic phrase is "push onto the stack".

The stack is a metaphor, like a stack of poker chips.  A poker chip is put onto the stack of chips, that is, placed on the top of the stack.

In real life, we usually remove the topmost item from a stack when we need to take an item from one. Hence its applicability to last-in-first-out programming scenarios. It's the opposite of a so-called FIFO queue (first in first out).

Comment: If the "stack" is something like a stack of poker chips, and you move them across the poker table, then you could say "push on the stack".

Comment: I don't know why, but in programming circles, they use the verb "push" to mean *place*. Items are *pushed onto* the stack" and *popped from* the stack. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pushed%20onto%20the%20stack%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: The OP needs to specify what "stack" means in the given examples. As is I would close this as needing more details.

Comment: It recognizable as a collocation from a specific domain. But have fun closing it if that's what pleases you.